# MySQL Join Table on three columns

Tags: mysql, join

I've got two tables

The first has user transactions:

```
Date    Transaction    P1    P2    P3    P4    P5
```

(P1-P5 are three digit user ID's)
Each transaction has 1, 2, 3, 4, and sometimes 5 users associated with it.

The second table has the user info:

```
ID    NAME    ACTIVE
```

I'm used to using a JOIN to display the user's NAMES as opposed to their ID, but with FIVE users, I have no idea how do display their names in my PHP/HTML table.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the same table for every user. If you do so you have to alias the multiple joined table differently.

```
select t1.Date, t1.Transaction, t1.P1, t1.P2, t1.P3, t1.P4, t1.P5
       u1.name, u2.name, u3.name, u4.name, u5.name
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 u1 on t1.p1 = u1.id
left outer join table2 u2 on t1.p2 = u2.id
left outer join table2 u3 on t1.p3 = u3.id
left outer join table2 u4 on t1.p4 = u4.id
left outer join table2 u5 on t1.p5 = u5.id
```

Comment: I was just writing pretty much that same answer.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks.
If I still need the three digit ID for linking in the PHP server side, how can I access them?

Comment: @dsol828: You can just add them to your query. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some fields will have `null` values if there are no `ID` on it.

```
SELECT  a.`Date, a.`Transaction`,
        b.name as P1Name, 
        c.name as P2Name, 
        d.name as P3Name, 
        e.name as P4Name, 
        f.name as P5Name
FROM    transactions a 
            LEFT JOIN info b
                on a.p1 = b.id
            LEFT JOIN info c
                on a.p1 = c.id
            LEFT JOIN info d
                on a.p1 = d.id
            LEFT JOIN info e
                on a.p1 = e.id
            LEFT JOIN info f
                on a.p1 = f.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place all the names in that 'td' separated with line break.